# extend geom_smooth in a single direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

You can extend a regression line in ggplot2 pretty easily:

```
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=wt, x=mpg)) + xlim(0,50)
c + stat_smooth(method=lm, fullrange=TRUE) + geom_point()
```

My question is, is it possible to extend in one direction only?

Before you ask, I have a good reason to do this, I promise!

Comment: So what's your desired outcome here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the internal workings of `stat_smooth`, `predictdf` is called to create the smoothed line. The difficulty here is : This is an S3 method not exported. It also don't take ... parameters so it is really difficult to extend it.

Here the idea is to create a new dummy classes `lm_right` and `lm_left` where we call the default `lm` method.

```
## decorate lm object with a new class lm_right
lm_right <- function(formula,data,...){
  mod <- lm(formula,data)
  class(mod) <- c('lm_right',class(mod))
  mod
}

## decorate lm object with a new class lm_left
lm_left <- function(formula,data,...){
  mod <- lm(formula,data)
  class(mod) <- c('lm_left',class(mod))
  mod
}
```

Then for each method we create a `predict_df` specialization where we truncate the x values in the opposite side.

```
predictdf.lm_right <- 
  function(model, xseq, se, level){
    ## here the main code: truncate to x values at the right
    init_range = range(model$model$x)
    xseq <- xseq[xseq >=init_range[1]]
    ggplot2:::predictdf.default(model, xseq[-length(xseq)], se, level)
  }
```

Same thing for the left extension :

```
predictdf.lm_left <- 
  function(model, xseq, se, level){
    init_range = range(model$model$x)
    ## here the main code: truncate to x values at the left
    xseq <- xseq[xseq <=init_range[2]]
    ggplot2:::predictdf.default(model, xseq[-length(xseq)], se, level)
  }
```

Finally a using example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
## you should set the fullrange option to a true 
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=wt, x=mpg)) + xlim(0,50) +  geom_point() +
     stat_smooth(method="lm_left", fullrange=TRUE,col='green') 
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=wt, x=mpg)) + xlim(0,50) +  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm_right", fullrange=TRUE,col='red') 

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Please, help modify your solution for the formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)

Comment: Excellent code. This functionality should be included in the next version of `ggplot2`.